# Nuget package publishes and different environments

Tags: tfs, azure-pipelines, devops, cicd

As most companies have, we have multiple environments and multiple build pipelines in Team Foundation Server (TFS) which are doing automated tests, builds, Nuget package publishes, ….

We are maintaining a Nuget package for local use, and I’ve come across a problem and wanted some advice from this community, hopefully I can get any good answers.

Let’s say, we have:

- 3 environments: Development -> Integration -> Production.
- 1 Nuget repository where we publish Nuget packages from our Integration environment.

If we increment the Nuget package from 1.0.0 to 1.0.1: that new version is published to the repository only during the Integration Build Pipeline.

It’s not a problem to reference the new version 1.0.1 when I’m working on my machine because I can generate that new package locally.
The problem occurs during the Development Build Pipeline: it won’t find the new version 1.0.1 in the Nuget repository yet because the Integration Build hasn’t occurred yet. Then the build step throws an exception about the version not present in the Nuget repository.

We don’t want to publish the package from Development environment, because those builds are in ‘Debug’ mode while integration environment is building in ‘Release’ mode.

Are there any suggestions or best practices on how we should take care of this?

Huge thanks for any insights.

We use TFS 2018 the old way, without yaml files.

Comment: Follow proper semantic versioning practices: Pre-release packages should be built normally following standard CI practices and have their pre-release status indicated in the version, such as '1.2.1-pre`. When a final version is published from a stable production branch, publish a version without a pre-release indicator. Tools like GitVersion can help you automate the generation and application of semantic version numbers.

Comment: Sounds like things might be a bit backwards here - ideally you have a pipeline which builds, tests and publishes NuGet packages for your lib, then you have an independent pipeline to build, test and release your application that references that lib

Comment: @rbennett485 indeed I need to guarantee that order of execution, I don't know if I can somehow make those build definitions depend on each other. Or call the other build definition when the one referencing the lib is started.